# How to add event listeners to lots of buttons with loop and Hide multi element accordingly?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button, addeventlistener

hi guys can anyone tell some ideas to add event listeners to these following button with loop and i want to hide 1st para if 1st button is clicked and 2nd para if 2nd button is clicked. How to do it i am trying to do it but cant get any ideas to do it .Please help me! thank you .

```
<body>
    <button class="btn">click1</button>
    <button class="btn">click2</button>
    <button class="btn">click3</button>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, veritatis.</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, tempore?</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, nisi!</p>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
            var r = document.getElementsByClassName("para");
            for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                for (var e = 0; e < r.length; r++) {
                    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                            r[e].style.display = "none";
                        })
                    }
                }

        })();

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id's to different `div` and then use the id value as class attributes for `p` tags. Without assigning unique identifiers it will be difficult to know which `p` tag to hide.

```js
window.onload = function() { onLoad(); }

function onLoad() {
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.querySelector("." + this.id).style.display = "none";
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="click1">click1</button>
<button class="btn" id="click2">click2</button>
<button class="btn" id="click3">click3</button>
<p class="click1">Click 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, veritatis.</p>
<p class="click2">Click 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, tempore?</p>
<p class="click3">Click 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, nisi!</p>
```